# Regex to extract last occurance of a digit/number after specfic keyword in java

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I have an input string with below format,

```
String str = "Remote system identifier 1.1.1.1, local AS number 100";
String str = "Remote system identifier 1.1.1.1, local AS number 100.100";
```

From the above strings I want to extract the number/String after the keyword "local AS number". So the expected output should be

```
100 
100.100
```

I tried the last occurrence of digit something like,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\D*$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

But is is not printing the expected value. Can we have pattern to extract some value after specific key word?

Comment: Did you really mean *after the keyword "local AS number"*? Or is it just so, that the input would always bind to the same pattern?

Comment: `"\\blocal AS number\\s+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)"` and grab `m.group(1)`

Comment: Yes, The number will always come after the keyword "local AS number"

Comment: "local AS number (\\d+.{0,1}\\d*)$" and m.group(1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
String str = "Remote system identifier 1.1.1.1, local AS number 100.100";
String localAsNumberText = "local AS number";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(localAsNumberText)+localAsNumberText.length()+1));
```